# Javascript: Calling a method stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to take advantage of Javascript closures by creating a method in one context and storing it in a global variable so that it may be called later from another context.

```
//Global variable to hold the function
var revertEvent;

//creates the function and assigns it to the global variable
 function createRevertFunction(eventToBeReverted) {

            revertEvent = function () {
                alert("Now Restoring Event");
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventToBeReverted, true);
            }          
  }
```

So, the "createRevertFunction" holds the state of the original object. That object "eventToBeReverted" is modified down the road after this function is called, so this provides a means to restore the original to the UI without page refresh.

My problem is that I can't seem to call the function in the variable "revertEvent".

I've tried:

```
revertEvent();
revertEvent.call();
window[revertEvent]();
```

and none of them work. Any help would be appreciated...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most likely problem here is that you're attempting to call `revertEvent` before it's been set via `createRevertFunction`.  To verify this change the declaration of `revertEvent` as follows

```
var revertEvent = function() { alert('not set yet'); }
```

This will pop up the alert "not seet yet" in the case it's called before `createRevertFunction`

Comment: I would also think that this is kind of his problem. @cinqoTimo when exactly in you code do you try to call the revertEvent function and when do you call createRevertFunction?

Answer (score 2):

make createRevertFunction return the interior function.  Assign.

```
var revertEvent;

//returns the function so we can do whatever with it
 function createRevertFunction(eventToBeReverted) {

        return function () {
            alert("Now Restoring Event");
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventToBeReverted, true);
        }          
  }


revertEvent = createRevertFunction(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> var revertEvent; 
undefined
>>> (function() {   revertEvent = function() { alert('hi') }   })();
undefined
>>> revertEvent()
```

This works for me. Show us your usage of the function, `createRevertFunction`...

Answer (score 0):

revertEvent is defined only inside your function and is forgotten afterwards. You will have to save it to a global variable (that is defined outside the function) or rather return the created function and store it.

Comment: revertEvent isn't defined in a function, and should have global scope.

Comment: revertEvent isn't local scope variable in this example.

Comment: Lol sorry you're right guys, didnt read well enough. Odd then.. will edit when found answer